# Adding wsdl or disco file to visual studio project not working as desired

Tags: c#, web-services

I am working on a development server and need to add reference to a web service which are hosted on another server behind TMG, which means I cannot simple add a service reference using url as it fails with 401.

Now me being clever, I created a console app on server with hosted services, added service reference to it, and now I got 3 files.

```
myservice.disco
myservice.wsdl
service reference myservice.reference.cs.dll
```

Now if I add `service reference myservice.reference.cs.dll` to my developemnt server project, I can get access to all methods but then i get this error,

> Description: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Service References.myservice.Reference.cs, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Don't know if that is related but I notice you have `myserviVe`, not `myserviCe` (my emphasis) in two places above.